# file reader doesn't get me the same string back

Tags: string, filereader, separator

I have a basic read from a .txt file but I can't figure it out why the string is different ?!

my text file has 10 lines of "zzz" on each line.
when I try to compare it with the string "zzz" is says they are not the same.
why ?
Is it because the reader is trying to read until the next separator ?
So, now the string has my "zzz" + separator ?
How can I delete that from my string ?
Can I make something like print(myString.length()-1) ?

This is the code.
I looked over something similar but I got nothing.

```
try { 
Scanner rf = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data Saved.txt")));
String fileLine;
while ( rf.hasNext()) {
fileLine = rf.next(); 
if(fileLine == "zzz") System.out.print("yes ");
else System.out.print("no ");
System.out.println(fileLine);

}
rf.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("Error IOException is: " + e);
}
```

The output is **no zzz** , 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `readLine` method  to avoid the line breaks, see 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--

Answer (score 0):

Thank you about that. I had no idea. I'll try to use it to see how it works.
I managed to deal with the problem using :

> if ( fileLine.equals("zzz") )

instead of

> if ( fileLine == "zzz" )

It seems that it works.